# how to auto submit a frame using javascript

Tags: javascript

HI
I have two frames, frame1 has few input text box and a submit .
on submit, frame2 shoudl display contents.
it is working on manual text enter and submit.
i am trying to make a auto submit . (i want the contents of a file to be continuously displayed in frame2 like unix tail cmd )

i wrote a function like

```
function refreshMe() {
setTimeout('refreshMe()', 5000);
var frm = document.getElementById("_form_");
frm.method="post"
 frm.action = "xyz.pl";
 frm.target="frame2"
 frm.submit() 
}
```

it is not working properly.
any idea ?

Edit:
I found out after commenting few code,
1) that the timer part is working fine.
but browser hangs only if I submit form
2) and document.forms["*form*"].submit()  is not working properly(it submits but with NULL values of all elements)

SO i tried using document.forms["*form*"].Submit.click()
it works but browser hangs after few (say 10 ) times of auto submit

Any idea please

Comment: Could you post a sample of the form code?

Answer (score 1):

I've just cleaned up your code a little bit. It may help fix the problem you are experiencing.

```
function frameRefresh()
{
    var frm = document.getElementById("_form_");
    frm.method = "post";
    frm.action = "xyz.pl";
    frm.target = "frame2";
    frm.submit();
}

var intervalId = setInterval(frameRefresh,5000);
```

Using `setInterval()` allows you to `clearInterval(intervalId)` at a later stage if you need to stop it from running.

Comment: thanks, I edited my Q with new observation , can you plz help

Comment: The code that I have here works fine for me, hasn't crashed and has run all morning. Could you provide your form code and perhaps the code of the page you are posting to? Also what browser are you using?